# In azure, is there any way to know who and when an app was published?

Tags: azure, webdeploy

We have an azure web app that we deploy with a publish profile and webdeploy. What I'd like to know is if there is any log about this deployment activity ? I read the logs but I can't find any trace of my deployments.

Note : we're not using git automated deployment

Comment: using web apps or cloud services?

Comment: we are using web apps

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure Management Portal (manage.windowsazure.com), select **Management Services** and then the **Operation Logs** tab.

[image]

Or, in the Azure Preview Portal (portal.azure.com), select **Browse All** and then **Audit Logs**.

Comment: I see many things there, what kind of message is supposed to be displayed on a  publish ?

Comment: You will see UpdateWebSite operations.  There's not a lot of data.  But, it will show you the site that was updated, when it was updated, and who updated it.

Comment: You can also click "Operation Logs" inside your website dashboard (quick glance). This will navigate directly to operations logs filtered by the specified website.

Comment: Is this supposed to be updated fast ? I just deployed my app twice (once without modification, once with a change) and I can't see anything yet

Comment: yes. Check date/time filter. Once you publish the project using VStudio it will instantly show in operation logs.

Comment: I don't believe deployments viw FTP / Web Publish direct from Visual Studio will ever be logged in these (Operation Logs / Audit Logs). There go only the Service Management API / ARM operations.

Comment: Yes, they are.  There is not much data logged, but they are there.  It may take a few minutes (I've seen up to 5) before you will see the log there.

Comment: I still don't have it (the last deploy was 1h ago), in portal or manage. Could it be a timezone problem ?

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd.  It works for me.  Try refreshing the page.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Just deployed using visual studio directly. Shows instantly.

Comment: are you guys (who see audit logs) deploying using the Publishe Profile or using Deployment Credentials?

Comment: Could it be because I'm using a free web app ?

Comment: @astaykov using web deploy.  Also, is not specific to pricing plan.